# how to set initial view (not tab) of a tabBarViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have 5 tabs in a tabBarViewController.

and the middle tab(3rd tab) is the main page.

so I want to set it as the initial view when user logs in.

I have searched a lot ways such as:

> 1. add selectedIndex in Attributes of tabBarViewController
>
>    2.add  `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2` in codes.

the initial tabs was tapped as what want I wanted. but the view was still the view of the first tab instead of the middle one.

### how to fix that?

in Appdelegate.swift

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController
if (login == true) //your condition if user is already logged in or not
{
    // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

    initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
}

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

in tabBarController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

Comment: It should work. Can you share the code

Comment: I`ve added codes in my question details.

Comment: add "initialViewController.selectedIndex = 2" in Appdelegate class

Comment: put that in `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.. it will work...